# Disable IntelliJ tab pop up notification

Tags: intellij-idea

I have disabled from IntelliJ > Preferences > Appearance & Behavior > Notifications all the Popups, and have also restarted the IDE, but haven't so far been able to disable the annoying popups that show the file location of each (tab) module I have open. Does any of you know how to disable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for "tooltip" in settings, and under "Editor Tabs", deselect the "Show tabs tooltips" checkbox.

[image: intellij-settings]

Comment: Thank you (writing more to by pass the 15 character limit ... )